# tracial state on a non-unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Does there exist a non-unital $C^*$ algebra which have uncountable tracial states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Let $X$ be an uncountable, non-compact, locally compact Hausdorff space (for example, $X=\mathbb R$), and consider the algebra $C_0(X)$.  This is non-unital, and the collection of all evaluation functionals $f\mapsto f(x)$ form an uncountable family of tracial states on $C_0(X)$.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Does there exist an ideal $I$ of $C_0(X)$ such that the dimensional of $C_0(X)/I$ is finite?

Comment: If $X$ has isolated points then yes.